# Co-variance: Normalize by N or N-1?

Tags: matlab, math, statistics

I'm working on calculating covariance by hand in matlab (without using the cov function). Anyway, I'm confused on why and when to normalize by N or N-1. I've been given sample data that is 2x400. Thus, two variable and 400 samples. Can anyone explain when a certain normalization is appropriate or is it slightly subjective? Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Normalization by N-1 is "correct" in the sense that the resulting estimator is unbiased. This means that if the sample number goes to infinity the covariance estimate approaches the true covariance.

If you would normalize by N, the estimation has (slightly) lower noise but is biased, i.e. gives the wrong result if N approaches infinity.

Note, that the above only applies if you don't know the mean value:
In case you would know the mean values, normalization by N is correct (you have to plug in the correct means in the formula as well, of course).

Comment: To use the technical terms, the division by 'N' is the maximum likelihood estimator, and the division by 'N-1' is the minimum variance unbiased estimator.

Answer (score 1):

For estimating the *variance*, using N-1 instead of N has the purpose of correcting estimation bias. See for example [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unbiased_estimation_of_standard_deviation). For *covariance* I guess it's the same idea.